# Git push/pull taking too long - IPv6 issue

Tags: ubuntu, git, ipv6

**My configuration:**

- ***laptop***: XPS 15 7590
- ***system***: Ubuntu 18.04
- ***internet* connection**: wifi (5 GHz)

Every time I run `git pull`, `git push` I have to wait like 15 minutes until it is done. Same problem with running `add-apt-repository ppa`. As I was trying to solve it, I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/500286/405138) where the solution was running:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

which is disabling IPv6 until next reboot. It really works. I would like to understand why exactly is this helping and also what can/should be done (set up) to make this permanent. And is it actually okay to set this permanently?

Comment: Possibly a problem with your DNS resolution in IPv6. `nmcli` in a terminal will list DNS servers associated with your network interfaces for IPv4 and IPv6. You can use these IPv6 address with `nslookup` to see if they work as servers. If not you can force IPv6 DNS in your network configuration (OpenDNS servers: `2620:119:35::35` and `2620:119:53::53`).

Comment: You probably should [check the state of your IPv6 connectivity](https://test-ipv6.com): if your router and/or your internet provider are announcing IPv6 capability (i.e. your laptop is receiving ICMPv6 router advertisements) but connections to remote IPv6 sites are actually dropped/misrouted/blocked, then disabling IPv6 would be a possible workaround until the underlying problem is fixed (either IPv6 connectivity is fixed or false IPv6 router advertisements are stopped). You might want to contact your internet provider to verify whether IPv6 is actually supposed to work for you or not.

Comment: I was checking router from my provider and ipv6 is disabled by default. Also https://test-ipv6.com/ does not detect ipv6.

Comment: You also need to make sure if your ISP supports ipv6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to make this permanent, open your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file using sudo

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add the line at the bottom of the file:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

After that you may reboot your machine or run

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

**Alternatively**, you may instruct your ssh client to use ipv4 only. To do so, open `~/.ssh/config` using `vi` or `nano` and add the following:

```
Host *
  AddressFamily inet
```

`AddressFamily` in the ssh config instructs which type of address to use when connecting via ssh. Valid choices are `any`, `inet`, `inet6`. Selecting to use `inet` makes sure ssh does not use ipv6 at all.

*Git (commands) use either ssh or http protocol when communicating over a network.* Since you are most likely using ssh protocol for your git commands, and making ssh protocol only use ipv4, it resolves the slow connectivity issue related to ipv6.

Unfortunately, this alternative approach won't fix your `add-apt-repository ppa`

Comment: And is it okay to disable it permanently? Couldn't it be missing at some point?

Comment: I would suggest using the alternative approach `~/.ssh/config` which does not disable ipv6 system-wide

Comment: Thanks! BTW this will also fix slow `add-apt-repository ppa`?

Comment: The ssh config thing won't fix `add-apt-repository ppa`

Comment: Thank you, I am accepting it as it works. Could you maybe also write why was it happening and what exactly happens when I set `AddressFamily inet`?

Comment: @matt525252 I have updated the answer with the explanation

Comment: Yes @matt525252 in this day and age you shouldn't disable IPv6 anymore. It can cause other performance problems. It is better to figure out the underlying problem.